Custom post type URL rewrite to have taxonomy category tree in Wordpress
I have custom post type with taxonomy categories and what I want to do is get rid of custom post type slug and have category with ancestors in url.
For example
categories:
– category
-- subcategory
--- subsubcategory
so url for post in subsubcategory should have URL:
website.com/category/subcategory/subsubcategory/post-name
Below is my code.
Actually in wp-admin post I have the correct URL, but when I visit that URL it gives the error 404 not found. When I manually change url to  website.com/subsubcategory/post-name then it shows.
function val_update_produkt_rewrite_rules() {
    $args = get_post_type_object('produkt');
    $args->rewrite = array(
        'slug' => '%product-categories%',
        'with_front' => false
    );
    register_post_type('produkt', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'val_update_produkt_rewrite_rules');

function val_custom_post_type_permalink($post_link, $post) {
    if ('produkt' === $post->post_type) {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'product-categories');
        if ($terms && !is_wp_error($terms)) {
            $term = $terms[0]; 
            $term_slug = $term->slug;
            $term_parents = get_ancestors($term->term_id, 'product-categories', 'taxonomy');

            if (!empty($term_parents)) {
                $parent_slugs = array_reverse(array_map(function($parent_id) {
                    $parent = get_term($parent_id, 'product-categories');
                    return $parent->slug;
                }, $term_parents));

                $term_slug = implode('/', $parent_slugs) . '/' . $term_slug;
            }

            return str_replace('%product-categories%', $term_slug, $post_link);
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'val_custom_post_type_permalink', 10, 2);

function val_update_categoria_produkt_rewrite_rules() {
    $args = get_taxonomy('product-categories');
    $args->rewrite = array(
        'slug' => '', 
    );
    register_taxonomy('product-categories', 'produkt', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'val_update_categoria_produkt_rewrite_rules');


Did you flush the permalinks?  Also you  modify your slug in post_type_link filter and then you run val_update_categoria_produkt_rewrite_rules which could be an issue.
